# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie persistent

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am using

```
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true)
```

As this cookie is persistent.

1) As such is there a need to even have timeout as this cookie 
will not have a timeout.

Notice how there is no timeout below.

```
     <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" cookieless="UseUri" />
```

2) To take care of browsers that do not allow for a cookie, 
is

```
     cookieless="UseUri"
```

the best way to go to where it uses a URL?

Comment: "Notice how there is no timeout below." - there is a timeout: if you don't specify it explicitly as in your example, it defaults to 30 minutes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I can tell you persistent cookies do timeout.  Read this [Forms Element for authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Regarding your question, sure--cookieless="UseUri" is useful on browsers that do not support cookies. But in my experience, it's considered bad pratice to use this flag, because:

1. Most browsers support cookies;
2. With cookieless="UseUri" two users can share session data, all they have to do is for one user to give out his application url to another user;

Comment: Thanks bastos - What do I do with users that are on older browsers or that have their cookie disabled. How do I handle these users That is why I  had cookieless = "Useuri"

Comment: Cookies have been around since 1995. Only the really, really old browsers don't implement cookies.  If the user disables cookies on his browser than too bad for him, just redirect him to an error page...  It's better than letting users share session.